# Expanding a table cell on clicking a button outside it in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [tableView beginUpdates]; // tell the table you're about to start making changes

    if ([indexPath compare:self.expandedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
       self.expandedIndexPath = nil;
    } else {
       self.expandedIndexPath = indexPath;
    }


[tableView endUpdates]; // tell the table you're done making your changes

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath compare:self.expandedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
       return 200.0; // Expanded height
   }
   return 44.0; // Normal height
```

}

```
- (void)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart didSelectSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
  This is a function of getting the index , when clicking a pie chart.
  what i need to do is expand the corresponding row of table when pie is    selected
}

@end
```

Comment: Please provide some code or logic what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got your idea you need to select the row at index path

```
- (void)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart didSelectSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    // get indexPath with index
    // remember if you have few sections then you will need to update inSection:0 value
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];

   [yourTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                               animated:NO 
                         scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

    // This will also Highlighted the row. Then delegate
    [yourTableView.delegate someTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: i cannot call my table function inside the pieChart function.i.e., "yourtableView" is showing error(I have given my table name itself)

Comment: also how will I expand the correct cell in correspondence to the slice selected in the pie chart

Comment: stop ... if you call table view you need to implement you table view as a weak property. But to be correct show full code

Comment: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView * yourTableView `

Comment: Nazir. it worked. Since you got the idea . can you also help me with the vice versa. i.e., if i choose  a row in the table i can pass the value to the pie chart to expand it. thanks in advance :)

Comment: use `setSliceSelectedAtIndex` where `index` is `indexPath.row` of selected row. Something like this: `[XYPieChart setSliceSelectedAtIndex: indexPath.row]`

Comment: It is not working it is showing the following error " No known class method for selector 'setSliceSelectedAtIndex:' " . Hope you can provide a solution.Thanks

Comment: `@class XYPieChart` has method `- (void)setSliceSelectedAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;` - so check the implementation

Comment: i am not able to do it. @Nazir

Comment: lets continue in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131254/expanding-a-table-cell-on-clicking-a-button-outside-it-in-objective-c

Comment: i am not able to chat..i am a noobie here and does not have enough points to able to do that :(

Comment: no i couldn't.  i tried all delegate methods available. i was able to pass the indexPath.row to the - (void)setSliceSelectedAtIndex:(NSInteger)index; but the pieChart din't animate.